# How to extract values from a xml request body with values in an array in wiremock

Tags: arrays, xml, xpath, each, wiremock

I am trying to extract line-item value from the below request body into my response in wiremock.

## Request:

```
**<request>
 <lineItem>
   <item> 
        <name> name </name>
        <quantity> 12 </quantity>
        <type>type</type>
</item>
</ lineItem>
<lineItem>
   <item> 
        <name> name2 </name>
        <quantity> 10 </quantity>
        <type>type2</type>
</item>
</ lineItem>
</request>**
```

## Expected Response:

```
**<response>
 <lineItem>
   <item> 
        <name> name </name>
        <quantity> 12 </quantity>
        <type>type</type>
</item>
</ lineItem>
<lineItem>
   <item> 
        <name> name2 </name>
        <quantity> 10 </quantity>
        <type>type2</type>
</item>
</ lineItem>
</response>**
```

I tried something like this:

```
    <response>
    {{#each (xPath request.body '/lineItem/item ') as |element| }}
     <lineItem>
       <item>  
       <quantity>  (xPath request.body '//lineItem/item/quantity/text()'}}</quantity>  
    </item>
    </ lineItem>
    </response>
```

but for 2 different  lineItem in request (as given above), I got 3 lineItem values in response and always getting the first item values in all the 3  lineItems:

## Response I got:

```
**<response>
 <lineItem>
   <item> 
        <quantity> 12 </quantity>
</item>
</ lineItem>
<lineItem>
   <item> 
        <quantity> 12 </quantity>
</item>
</ lineItem>
<lineItem>
   <item> 
        <quantity> 12 </quantity>
</item>
</ lineItem>
</response>**
```

Can someone help me with this scenario?

Comment: I don't know Wiremock's XPath parser, but your XPaths look invalid, since you place spaces in between the path components: `// lineItem/ item /quantity/text()`. Have you tried `//lineItem/item /quantity/text()`? Also, instead of using `text()` as the last component, you may want to prefer `data()`, which is more robust or, as second choice, `string()`. However, `data()` is available for XPath >2.1 only, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @amix The space was a typo here, I don't have any spaces in between the path components. I am getting the <quantity> value, but the quantity value is from the first item and the same quantity value is shown for all the items. I tried `string()` and  `data()`, getting not a valid XPath expression error.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you then. Probably your engine is using XPath1.0. But that's not even the issue here. I see, that you only query `quantity` and not the other items. Maybe if you also do `<name>  (xPath request.body '//lineItem/ item/name/text()'}}</name>` and `<type>  (xPath request.body '//lineItem/ item/type/text()'}}</type>`

If you got the permissions could you be so kind as to edit your question to remove the typos and fix the formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem today. I also needed to get a list of values from a request and create in response as many objects based on this as I received.
If we shift the solution to your question, then it will looks like this:

```html
<response>
  {{#each (xPath request.body '//lineItem/item/quantity') as |element| }}
  <lineItem>
     <item>  
       <quantity>{{element.text}}</quantity>  
     </item>
  </lineItem>
  {{/each}}
</response>
```